# Does firebase auth store and manage access token for different provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication, facebook-access-token

I am working on a flutter app where the user will sign-in using Facebook. Later I want to access facebook graph API and for then I need the access token of the user.

I of now I am storing the access token in firestore and assessing from there. But is there any way using which we can get the access token from currentUser. Because in the current situation the access then gets expired and I need to refresh it again and again. Does firebase handle it automatically?

Below is my code which I use to sign in with Facebook using firebase.

```
FacebookLogin facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
FacebookLoginResult result = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends']);
switch (result.status) {
    case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        AuthCredential authCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: result.accessToken.token);
            FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCredential)).user;
        //Here I save user details in firestore
}
```

Comment: You mean later if you use firebaseAuthInstance.currentUser() then you are not able to get the token of this user?

Comment: @LoVe, Yes, later I want to get the accessToken to call the Facebook graph API.

Comment: var res = await firebaseUser.getIdToken();
 String token = res.token;

this doesn't work?have you tried it?

Comment: I tried this, but this token is not a Facebook access token.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you will need to set up your own token via Facebook's sign in system. When you sign in using Facebook, you can configure it such that their token IS the Facebook token as well.

Check out [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login) for a from-scratch Facebook login.

And [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for creating a custom Firebase token.